# VS 2017 shows incorrect C++ Unicode literals during debugging

Tags: visual-studio, unicode, c++17

When I try to define Unicode string literals in C++(17) I see some very odd results during debugging, which I would like to discuss. Look at the following variable definitions:

```
std::string u8 { u8"⬀⬁" };
std::string u8_1 { u8"\u2B00\u2B01" };
std::u16string u16 { u"⬀⬁" };
std::u16string u16_1 { 0x2B00, 0x2B01 };
std::u32string u32 { U"⬀⬁" };
std::u32string u32_1 { 0x2B00, 0x2B01 };

std::string u8_2 { u8"\u2B00⬀⬁" };
std::u16string u16_2 { u"\u2B00⬀⬁" };
std::u32string u32_2 { U"\u2B00⬀⬁" };
```

During debugging I now get the following strings:

[image]

As you can see the values are pretty surprising. Strings defined with an initializer list or escape codes appear correct, while those specified as normal characters appear as if they were UTF-8 encoded and the bytes are written to the strings. This is correct for an UTF-8 string (u8_1 here), but not for UTF-16 and UFT-32 strings  (u16 and u32 here). And what's even more odd is the fact that the u8 variable contains values that are doubly UTF-8 encoded. You can easily prove that with an online UTF converter. If the debugger was the problem I wouldn't see some correct values, but since it shows values correct that have been specified with escape sequence, I assume something else is guilty for messing up the strings.

What would explain the results somehow is when the file is UTF-8 encoded and that would directly have taken over to string variables, without any conversion. Though I think the original string in the C++ file should be converted from the source encoding (which is indeed UTF-8) to the correct target encode, instead. Needless to say this works as expected in XCode.

Is this a known problem? Can this somehow worked around to avoid having to use numeric values instead?

Comment: windows assumes that all `char` byte strings are in the user locale, not UTF-8. The debugger is most likely assuming that too.

Comment: especially since `std::string`/`char` and has no inherent charset encoding of its own, unlike `std::u8string`/`char8_t` in C++20 which would always be UTF-8 (just like `std::u16string`/`char16_t` is always UTF-16, and `std::u32string`/`char32_t` is always UTF-32).

Comment: The point here however is that the encoding of the string literal is well known (UTF-8, the file encoding), so it's easy to convert that to the target encoding (at least for u16string and u32string). Other compilers can do that very well, why not MSVC?